# MS Graph API returns 500 when I try to request groups

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

So I am developing a sharepoint webpart where I need to check if a user is in an AD group. Now here is the odd part the MS Graph query I need to you for that is:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/transitiveMemberOf/microsoft.graph.group?$count=true
```

And that is the exact Query that my WP sends out, but it returns a 500 error message. Now I thought I had permissions missing, but the Explorer says I do not need any.

Here is my GraphService that handles MS Graph:

```
import { MSGraphClient } from '@microsoft/sp-http';
import * as MicrosoftGraph from '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types';
import { WebPartContext } from "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base";

/**
 * The class that handles the MS Graph API calls
 */
export default class GraphService {
    /**
     * The MS Graph client with does the calls
     */
    private _client:MSGraphClient;

    /**
     * Sets the client for the Graph API, needs to be called before the class can be used
     * @param context The context of the WP
     */
    public async setClient(context:WebPartContext) {
        this._client = await context.msGraphClientFactory.getClient();
    }
    /**
     * Checks to see if a user belongs in a user group or not
     * @param groupName The group name with we want to check
     */
    public async checkCurrentUserGroup(groupName:string) {
        const rawData = await this._client.api('/me/transitiveMemberOf/microsoft.graph.group').count(true).get();
        const arr = rawData.value.filter(i => i.displayName == groupName);
        return !!arr.length;
    }


    /**
     * Returns the users from AD who have a manager and whom companyName is a specific company name
     * @param companyName The company name to whom the users need to belong to
     */
    public async getUsers(companyName:string):Promise<any[]> {
        const rawData = await this._client.api('/users').filter('accountEnabled eq true').expand('manager').select('displayName,companyName,mail,department,jobTitle').get();

        //need to do manual filtering, becuase you can't user filter on the "companyName" field and you can't search and expand at the same time without returing everything
        const filteredData = rawData.value.filter(i => i.companyName == companyName && i.manager);

        //remaps the data to IUserModel
        const ret:any[] = filteredData.map(i => <any>{
            name: i.displayName,
            id: 0,
            email: i.mail,
            manager: i.manager.displayName,
            managerEmail: i.manager.mail,
            managerId: 0,
            hasDiscussionForm: false,
            department: i.department,
            position: i.jobTitle
        });

        return ret;
        
    } 
}
```

The problem then is that the method `checkCurrentUserGroup` returns 500.

I've given the following permissions to the wp:

- Group.Read.All
- Directory.Read.All
- User.Read

The `getUsers` method works as expected.

In the MS Graph Explorer the query works just fine. What am I missing?

Comment: can you please try by passing header details `client.api('/users/{id}/transitiveMemberOf/microsoft.graph.group')
 .header('ConsistencyLevel','eventual')` let us know if it helps

Comment: @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity no I had not and that actually worked ty, can you give an answer so I can accept it and maybe an explanation as to what happened for me, if its not too much to ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the document the request header must have ConsistencyLevel and eventual header and please make sure to pass the request header and please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-transitivememberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript) for more information

```
let res = await client.api('/users/{id}/transitiveMemberOf/microsoft.graph.group')
    .header('ConsistencyLevel','eventual')
    .search('displayName:tier')
    .select('displayName,id')
    .orderby('displayName ')
    .get();
```